# Rails Testing a named_scope with a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, named-scope, testcase

**SCENARIO**
I have a named_scope on a model called 'last_week'. All it does is it fetches the records from last week.

I want to test this and my approach is to test that the results coming back are within a certain range. I don't know if this is the right way of testing this functionality on a class method.

I can't use RSpec, Shoulda or other 3rd party client plugin. I am only allowed to use Mocha if I want.

```
# Model

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :last_week,   :conditions => { :created_at => 1.week.ago..DateTime.now.end_of_day }

end


#Test

class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "named scope :last_week " do
    last_week_range = DateTime.now.end_of_day.to_i - 1.week.ago.to_i
    assert_in_delta last_week_range, Article.last_week.first.created_at - Article.last_week.last.created_at,  last_week_range
  end

end
```

Looking for feedback on what's right or wrong about this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your scope is wrong: because code is executed on the fly your date range condition will depend on the time you booted your server...

Replace with:

```
scope :last_week,  lambda { :conditions => { :created_at => 1.week.ago..DateTime.now.end_of_day } }
```

Second, to test, I'd create some records and check if the scope get the proper ones:

- create a factory
- create two records
- set `created_at` 1 week + 1 day ago for one record
- check your scope only retrieves one (the proper one)

Comment: 1. Thanks for pointing out the lambda tip     

2. So I am using fixtures and in my fixtures I know 3 records that are within the scope of :last_week. Is it bad to write the test like this
  
`test "scope :last_week" do
  assert_equal 3, Article.last_week.count
end`

Comment: Fixtires are not dynamic (unless you add ruby code inside), your test will fail next week + you must always check that your code does what you expect (find Entry in timeframe) AND rejects bad values (doesn't find entries outside timeframe)

Comment: I have some ruby code in the fixtures to have the dates appear dynamic for created_at: <%= DateTime.now %>.

I guess I'm wondering if I can do what you mentioned with fixtures alone OR do I need to investigate a 3rd party plugin like FactoryGirl?

Comment: Make sure to use a gem like Timecop to freeze the time during the test or you'll get some strange failures in your automated test framework because the test ran exactly at midnight.