# Calculating non-Rolling Last Week in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Article and what I want to do is show all of the Articles where the created_at date was for last week.  I understand how to a rolling week (ie the last 7 days to now), such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204010/rails-testing-a-named-scope-with-a-date-range).

```
scope :last_week,  lambda { :conditions => { :created_at => 1.week.ago..DateTime.now.end_of_day } }
```

However, what I want to do is to find the Articles that were Sunday - Saturday of last week, regardless of what day the current day is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to John's answer, but I think this fits your situation a little better:

```
scope :last_week, lambda { { conditions: { created_at: last_week_range } } }

def self.last_week_range
  1.week.ago.beginning_of_week(:sunday)..1.week.ago.end_of_week(:sunday)
end
```

Comment: When I add this and use Article.last_week I get a syntax error.  "unexpected ':', expecting ')'

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using? I used the 1.9 hash syntax here.

Comment: Ah, typo on my part. Fixed now.

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize 'last_week_range" as a method.  When I do Article.last_week, I get "NameError: undefined local variable or method 'last_week_range'.

Comment: Ah, it needs to be a class method. Fixed. There are probably better places to put the method though, I just put it there for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a helper method to get the beginning and end of a week for a given date. The method defaults to monday so you have to pass in sunday to override it.

```
  scope :last_week,  lambda { :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today.at_beginning_of_week(:sunday)..Date.today.at_end_of_week(:sunday) } }
```

I have usen Date.today as an example but you could have the scope have a date argument so you could apply any date to the scope.

**Edit:**

```
scope :last_week, lambda{ |date| {:conditions => ((date - 1.week).at_beginning_of_week(:sunday))..((date-1.week).at_end_of_week(:sunday)) }}
```

then just call the scope as

```
last_week(some_date)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get 3/31 as the start date.  How would I adjust to always be referring to the week prior (ie 3/24)?

Comment: Thanks.  When I edit the scope and call Article.last_week(Date.today) I get a syntax error.  unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}' (it points to after ":conditions =>" )

Comment: When I try Article.last_week(Date.today), I get the error "TypeError: Cannot visit Range"

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse` gives an awesome results being run on the weekday name:

```
require 'date'
# ⇒ true
Date.today
# ⇒ <Date: 2013-04-02 ((2456385j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.parse('Sunday')
# ⇒ <Date: 2013-03-31 ((2456383j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.parse('Wednesday')
# ⇒ <Date: 2013-04-03 ((2456386j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

So all you need is:

```
def last_weekend
  d = Date.parse('Saturday')
  d -= 7 if d > Date.today
  Range.new d, d+1
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to work if the Date is in the future, for example if I do it for Date.parse('Wednesday).  However, what I was looking for is last week being 2013-03-24 to 2012-03-30, instead of 2013-03-31 to 2013-04-06.

Comment: `d = Date.parse('Saturday')` ⇒ `#<Date: 2013-04-06 ((2456389j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` || `d -= 7 if d > Date.today` ⇒ 
`#<Date: 2013-03-30 ((2456382j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` || `Range.new d, d+1` ⇒ `#<Date: 2013-03-30 ((2456382j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2013-03-31 ((2456383j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` — isn’t that what you were looking for?